# Joining two queries into one

Tags: sql

I have two working queries.  Query 1 performs a filter on a large table and returns exactly the data that I need, it looks like this:

```
/****** QUERY #1 - This query will filter the data  ******/
  SELECT [WacnId],
   [StartDT]
  ,[EndDT]
  ,[Group]
  ,[ID_Agency]
  ,[TargetUnit_Agency],


  case [Group]
  when 1 then 'in'
  when 0 then 'out'
  end as traffic

FROM [GW_20140315].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]

WHERE [GroupDisplayID] = 'T802149' OR [ID_Agency] = 'Dispatch' or [TargetUnit_Agency] =   'Dispatch'
order by StartDT
```

Query #2 acts on the filtered data from Query 1 and produces a 1/2 hourly report.  Query 2 looks like this:

```
/******Query #2-  This query will take the filtered data and process it as needed  ******/
SELECT dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) as HalfHour
   , sum(DATEDIFF ( s , [StartDT] , [EndDT] )) as [Total Time (Seconds)],
   SUM(CASE WHEN [TargetUnit_Agency] = 'Dispatch' then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS InCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN [ID_Agency] = 'Dispatch' then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OutCount
FROM  [Radio].[dbo].[Filter_Data]--This is how I did it before, but now I want to combine the two  queries
GROUP BY dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) 
ORDER BY 1
```

How may I combine these two queries into one?

Comment: Is [Radio].[dbo].[Filter_Data] a temp table or a view or a subquery?

Comment: Do you want to `UNION` them (join them together vertically as two lists) or correlate them on something (join them). You'll need to provide some sample input and output data.

Comment: Just replace `[Radio].[dbo].[Filter_Data]` with the Query 1 enclosed in brackets and you are good

Comment: What's your DB server? MySQL has some performance issues with SubQueries, so try to avoid them. And always think about, if something could be done in pure SQL, it doesn't mean it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a CTE to describe your filtered data (first query) and then query using the CTE as your main table (second query):

```
;WITH FilteredCTE AS
(
    SELECT [WacnId],
     [StartDT]
    ,[EndDT]
    ,[Group]
    ,[ID_Agency]
    ,[TargetUnit_Agency],
    case [Group]
        when 1 then 'in'
        when 0 then 'out'
    end as traffic
    FROM [GW_20140315].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
    WHERE [GroupDisplayID] = 'T802149' 
        OR [ID_Agency] = 'Dispatch' 
        or [TargetUnit_Agency] =   'Dispatch'
)
SELECT dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) as HalfHour,
sum(DATEDIFF ( s , [StartDT] , [EndDT] )) as [Total Time (Seconds)],
SUM(CASE WHEN [TargetUnit_Agency] = 'Dispatch' then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS InCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN [ID_Agency] = 'Dispatch' then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OutCount
FROM  FilteredCTE
GROUP BY dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) 
ORDER BY StartDT
```

Comment: This does what I needed, but it had issues when executed with the order by StartDT line, so I removed it and it runs fine and interesting the table was sorted by StartDT, which is good, but I do need to make sure this always happens.  Do I need to add an order by StartDT somewhere?

Comment: @eltel2910 This was my bad, you may not have an order by within CTE definition. You need to define the order in the final select.

Comment: @Paraskevopoulos, yup reasoned my way through it, but I couldn't have done it without your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just select Query1 FROM Query2:

```
SELECT Dateadd(mi, ( Datediff(mi, 0, startdt) / 30 ) * 30, 0) AS HalfHour, 
       Sum(Datediff (s, [startdt], [enddt]))                  AS 
       [Total Time (Seconds)], 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [targetunit_agency] = 'Dispatch' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end)                                               AS InCount, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [id_agency] = 'Dispatch' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end)                                               AS OutCount 
FROM   (SELECT [wacnid], 
               [startdt], 
               [enddt], 
               [group], 
               [id_agency], 
               [targetunit_agency], 
               CASE [group] 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'in' 
                 WHEN 0 THEN 'out' 
               end AS traffic 
        FROM   [GW_20140315].[dbo].[arc_calls_reportview] 
        WHERE  [groupdisplayid] = 'T802149' 
                OR [id_agency] = 'Dispatch' 
                OR [targetunit_agency] = 'Dispatch' 
        ORDER  BY startdt) 
GROUP  BY Dateadd(mi, ( Datediff(mi, 0, startdt) / 30 ) * 30, 0) 
ORDER  BY 1
```